# Axios routing in Vue 2 - development and production baseApiURL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I've followed this tutorial to set up mongoDB with Vue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek50iuo5zkE&ab_channel=DesignCourse

Once I deployed to my VPS, only the development (localhost) side works, I'm getting these errors on production from axios requests to the database:

```
xhr.js:210 POST 404 (Not Found) axios
```

I rewatched the tutorial and I believe the only thing I did differently was to choose Vue 2 rather than Vue 3 (I have other projects in Vue 2 and just chose it out of familiarity).

Would this cause the error?

In my `App.vue` file, where the axios requests are, I have this:

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      baseApiURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL,
```

`.env.development` file is:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL=http://localhost:4000/api
```

`.env.production` file is:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL=https://mydomainname.com/api
```

In `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "MONGO_CONNNECTION_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydomainname node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Has the way that this worked changed between Vue 2 and Vue 3 -- if so, how do I do this in Vue 2 / or should I just restart from Vue 3?

Comment: The question lacks necessary information. *I'm getting these errors on production from axios requests to the database* - which url? How exactly do you switch between dev and prod? The most obvious reason would be that you have wrong environment on deployment, so wrong base url is used

Comment: @EstusFlask, I'm getting the errors using the production URL, e.g. ``https://example.com/api/get-crypto``. I thought my ``VUE_APP_BASE_API_URL`` info was sufficient for showing how to switch between dev and prod, like in the tutorial, what extra info should I provide?

Comment: If you have errors, they need to be exhaustive. Request errors can be backed with info from network tab. https://example.com/api/get-crypto - is this url you do requests to ? Do you see this in network tab? If the expected url gives 404 then it's specific to back end which isn't shown, not Vue. You still didn't say how you build dev/prod app. It won't know which environment to use by magic.

Comment: You can keep tutorial link but for reference only, the question should be perfectly understandable without navigating to external links, this is required by SO rules. It matters what exactly you did, not what a tutorial says. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve